# Box2D - collision system weirdnes, fixtures too big

Tags: c++, box2d

I used Box2D few times with C++ but first time I see such a thing.
I had created two objects, both same width and height of 25 pixels. First one initial position is [25, 25]and second one is [25, 75] When I move first body up the collision starts at [25, 25]. Also when first object starts at [25,200] and is moving down collision starts at [25, 125]. It looks like fixtures are bigger then should be.

Here is Box2D realeted part of code:

```
        void createBody(bool dynamic)
        {
            /* == === === ==
                Init Part
            == === === == */
            double x = _x;
            double y = _y;

            double w = _w;
            double h = _h;

            /* == === === ==
                Body part
            == === === == */
            b2BodyDef bDef;
            bDef.fixedRotation = true;
            if (dynamic)
                bDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;
            else
                bDef.type = b2_staticBody;

            bDef.position.Set(x, y);

            _body = Urd::Utilities::Box2dThingy::getInstance().getWorld()->CreateBody(&bDef);

            /* == === ===== === ==
                Fixture part
            == === ===== === == */
            b2FixtureDef fDef;

            fDef.density = 0;

            //SHAPE
            b2PolygonShape r;
            r.SetAsBox(w, h);

            fDef.shape = &r;


            _body->CreateFixture(&fDef);
        };
```

Any idea?

EDIT:

Ok I found SDL version for DebugDraw. It looks like that

```
        SDL_Rect poly;
        poly.x = vertices[0].x;
        poly.y = vertices[0].y;
        poly.w = (vertices[0].x - vertices[1].x) > 0 ? vertices[0].x - vertices[1].x : vertices[1].x - vertices[0].x;
        poly.h = (vertices[0].y - vertices[1].y) > 0 ? vertices[0].y - vertices[1].y : vertices[1].y - vertices[0].y;
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(_renderer, 255, 255, 255, 255);
        SDL_RenderFillRect(_renderer, &poly);
```

but it doesn't work because h ALWAYS equals 0. It does equals 0 because vertices[0].y always equals vertices[1].y.
Also values of vertices aren't correct. Position of object is [50,25] but vertices x and y equals [25, 0].

Any idea?

Comment: Enable the debug draw and have a look. Also whats the scaling?

Comment: To ensure that I didn't forget to scale any important variable scale is set to 1.0. I forgot about debug draw... I'll check that when I'll arrive home.